# How to trigger masonry plugin to readjust arrangment

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry

I am using JQuery Masonry plugin with Bootstrap 3 in my project. However, Masonry frequently did not properly placing element when it's first loaded or when the div size is changed by JavaScript. However, as soon as I resize my browser, the placing of elements are adjusted and placed properly.

So, my question is how can I trigger Masonry plugin to re-adjust the placing of elements with JavaScript?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use the `bindResize` method that binds mansonry with the resize of the window. Also, if you call mansonry a second time without any argument or method, it's equivalvent to a refresh.

Comment: Try `.masonry( 'reload' )`